# Binding Model and ViewModel for a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am relatively new to WPF and I try to show some data in a `ListView`.

I have a Model class `Order` which I want to simply show on the `ListView`. But I want to also show some other calculated informations (such as amount of `Positions` inside the order).

How do I achieve to use the `OrderViewModel` (ViewModel) and not the `Order` (Model) class for the `DataTemplate` of the `ListView`?

Please tell me if you need more informations.

Thank you in advance!

**Order class**

This is my order class. It contains some information, but not everything I want to show on the ListView.

```
public class Order
{
    private int number;
    private ObservableCollection<Position> positions;


    /// <summary>
    /// Default Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Order()
    {
        this.positions = new ObservableCollection<Position>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Order Number
    /// </summary>
    public int Number
    {
        get { return number; }
        set { number = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Positions inside the order.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Position> Positions
    {
        get { return positions; }
        set { positions = value; }
    }
}
```

**Order ViewModel**

This class is the ViewModel I want to show on the ListView.

```
public class OrderViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    readonly private Order order;

    #region Constructor

    public OrderViewModel(Order order)
    {
        this.order = order;
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Order Properties

    public string Number
    {
        get { return order.Number.ToString(); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Position> Positions
    {
        get
        {
            return order.Positions;
        }
    }

    #endregion Order Properties

    #region Presentation Properties

    public int AmountOfPositions // Calculated value should be shown on the ListView.
    {
        get { return order.Positions.Count; }
    }

    #endregion Presentation Properties
}
```

**XAML of the ListView**

```
  <ListView x:Name="orderListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableOrders}" Margin="0,54,0,0" SelectionMode="Single" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOrder}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AmountOfPositions}" // This does not work! />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: I think..In properties Add get as well as set and RaisePropertyChange to notify it on the view

Comment: what type is AvailableOrders.

Comment: @JustinCI I can't bind the Property AmountOfPositions, because the Model class has not got that property. The ListView is using the MODEL directly and not the ModelView (OrderViewModel)

Comment: @y0io it's of type Order. Do you think I have to use the ViewModel in the list? Isn't there a way to "automatically" use the ViewModel when I'm using the class Order?

Comment: assign values in view model then set the DataContext

Comment: @JustinCI Yes of course, use ViewModel in collection :) It is common way

Comment: @y0io you are absolutely right. I tought there is a way to express this via XAML. Thank you for your support.

Comment: @JustinCI there is way to express it via XAML but it is ugly workaround. You're welcome

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to [set the DataContext](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/37f2b458-127d-4e12-82c8-419103f08c6b/setting-datacontext-in-xaml-mvvm?forum=wpf) of your XAML to the viewmodel.
2. You need to [raise the property changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event that is ultimately exposed via your ViewModelBase